# Why does VS2015 apply breakpoints from one project to another?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I created a solution in Visual Studio 2015 Community (Update 3) with two projects in it. Each project has this code in a file called tiny.cpp:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

int tiny()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The main routine, in Project1.cpp, is this:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

extern int tiny();

int main()
{
    tiny();
    return 0;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the `return` statement in `tiny`, the debugger correctly catches it and shows the code in the IDE. However, if I create a second project in the same solution, with an identical file called tiny.cpp, and a file called Project2.cpp with code identical to that in Project1.cpp, and start that project in the debugger, *with no breakpoints set in either of the files in the second project*, the debugger behaves as though the breakpoints set in the first project's `tiny` function are set in the second project's `tiny` function.

If, in the second project I set a single breakpoint at the `}` in `tiny` and start the second project in the debugger, *both* breakpoints show when the debugger catches either of them, one from the first project's copy of tiny.cpp and one from the second project's copy of tiny.cpp.

Interestingly, the behavior goes away if *any* change is made to *either* version of tiny.cpp, even just adding a comment at the end of a line (so the line numbers don't even change). More interestingly, making the *same* change to both versions (so they are different than before the change, but remain the same as each other after the change) does *not* make the behavior go away.

This played heck with me this morning when I copied a bunch of source files from one project to another. The breakpoints from the originals continued to affect the copies, making me think, for a while, that I was still running the old code, not the copied version.

Can anyone tell me why VS2015 exhibits this behavior? Is there any useful purpose to it?

Here's a screenshot I've tried to upload to Microsoft, but their uploader never seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Breakpoints have file scope, not project scope.  I got an accidental repro for this behavior.  You need to change a setting: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Require source files to exactly match the original version" checkbox.  You can still call it a bug, no argument from me, use connect.microsoft.com to report it.

Comment: Thanks, @Hans , that option is already ticked in my IDE. Unticking it allows this odd behavior to persist even after I make a change to one of the files. When ticked, it behaves as I've described above, with identical source files effectively applying the set union of their breakpoints. I've reported it at connect, but that site seems kind of iffy, to me. They want screenshots, so I made one, but none of the attachments I've uploaded ever appear. My last report before this one just disappeared entirely after a few days. Odd, eh?

Comment: Following up: That option is to prevent the programmer from accidentally using a source file for debugging when that source file has been changed after compilation. Unfortunately, it doesn't address the problem we are talking about here which, as you point out, is because the breakpoints are set by file, not by project, and the debugger apparently thinks all files name "x.cpp" are the same file, when setting breakpoints.